# Split block of text into separate parts

Tags: r, regex

New to R so apolgies if this is obvious..
Given a text document containing a sample block of text such as the following:

> Deputy Kermit: Sir, providing access to good education for all the
>   Utoppia's children is one of our most important responsibilities as
>   States’ Members. We all recognise that. On the morning we began to
>   debate the future of selection in secondary education that was why
>   feelings ran so high, and why it was so closely fought.
>
> But our responsibility does not stop at the doors of this Assembly.
>   For the sake of practicality we delegate day-to-day policy
>   responsibilities to individual Committees. As Deputy Fozzy has rightly
>   said, the Committee is the agent of the States. Ultimately it should
>   do what it is told. So there should be no doubt that the buck stops
>   with us, the States, to be sure that our agent, the Committee, has the
>   skills, strength and experience necessary for the task we have
>   assigned to it. If the Committee is not the right one for the task
>   ahead, especially if it is a task of vital importance to our Island,
>   then it is our duty to deal with that. We must remember that there is
>   no hierarchy here, no power to hire or fire discreetly in this
>   Assembly. If a Committee is in the wrong job but it does not step
>   down, the only tool we have to manage that is a motion of no
>   confidence.
>
> Deputy Fozzy’s record too is similar, he just said that change is a
>   recipe for disaster. On the steps of the States after December’s
>   debate he told us that Utopia would rue –
>          The Bailiff: Deputy Fozzy.
>
> Deputy Fozzy: That was never said on the steps of this Assembly
>   after the debate. I have said nothing ever like that after the debate.
>   I think you need to check your facts.
>          The Bailiff: Through the Chair,
>          Deputy Kermit: I repeat what I heard in the media, sir.

I would like to split each speakers statements out into their own separate file. What are my options to do this, given the speakers title (in this example Deputy or Baliff) and the character ':' may also occur within the block of text?

Comment: What is regular about this text? What blocks do you need to extract and what are the rules to extract them? Have you tried anything so far and if yes, please share to see where your problem is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It would appear that each paragraph is separated by only one crlf, whereas a change of speaker carries two.  Haven't tried anything of note as of yet, but I'd want to split out the paragraphs (or sentences) grouped by the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the sentence breaks here...just an attempt.

Regex:

```
    (^|[\W\S]\s*)(([A-Z][a-z]+\s?)+:)
```

Replacement:

```
    $1\n\n$2
```

Output:

Deputy Kermit: Sir, providing access to good education for all the Utoppia's children is one of our most important responsibilities as States’ Members. We all recognise that. On the morning we began to debate the future of selection in secondary education that was why feelings ran so high, and why it was so closely fought.
But our responsibility does not stop at the doors of this Assembly. For the sake of practicality we delegate day-to-day policy responsibilities to individual Committees. As Deputy Fozzy has rightly said, the Committee is the agent of the States. Ultimately it should do what it is told. So there should be no doubt that the buck stops with us, the States, to be sure that our agent, the Committee, has the skills, strength and experience necessary for the task we have assigned to it. If the Committee is not the right one for the task ahead, especially if it is a task of vital importance to our Island, then it is our duty to deal with that. We must remember that there is no hierarchy here, no power to hire or fire discreetly in this Assembly. If a Committee is in the wrong job but it does not step down, the only tool we have to manage that is a motion of no confidence.
Deputy Fozzy’s record too is similar, he just said that change is a recipe for disaster. On the steps of the States after December’s debate he told us that Utopia would rue –

The Bailiff: Deputy Fozzy.

Deputy Fozzy: That was never said on the steps of this Assembly after the debate. I have said nothing ever like that after the debate. I think you need to check your facts.

The Bailiff: Through the Chair,

Deputy Kermit: I repeat what I heard in the media, sir.

Comment: This is not R code though.. might want to wrap the regex in an R function